How do I create camera motion in a heavy scene animation?
When the viewport FPS drops to 1, what are you to do? Even with the highest-end graphics card I am struggling to manage my camera motion artistically. Can I create a bounding-box rendition of the file? What kind of 'simplify' modifier would dissolve the scene to resolve to 30 FPS?
There is simply no way to get clever with camera timing or motion, for a quality product, when the frame rate drops so low. Suppressing collections doesn't work, by the way.

Usually people do viewport renders to check if the animation looks okay at the right speed. You'll find it in the viewport menu under View > Viewport Render Animation.
It renders much quicker than a real render, uses the settings in the Output Properties and renders from the camera if you are in camera view or any other view which you are currently looking at - without having to set up a camera for that.
This has the advantage you can perhaps focus on certain parts of the animation or views which are not so easy to see from the camera but are important to you. Or quickly change viewing angles just to see if they might be better.
